# Problem about convolution and diffusion equation (Fourier)

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I am trying to understand how to solve a problem (It's in a Fourier Chapter) .

Here the statement :

If $u(\theta,t)$ is the temperature at a time $t$ at the point $(R,\theta)$ in polar coordinates on a conduction circle. And that the temperature is following the diffusion equation : $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$

Express $u$ as a convolution by $\theta$ :

$u(\theta,t)=g(\theta,t) \circledast u(\theta,0)$

where $g$ need to be precised and $\circledast$ is the circular convolution :

$(x \circledast y)(\theta):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}x(u)y(\theta-u)du$.

Thank by advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

This is the standard *Heat equation* and you don't need to use convolution as it throws you off the simple and convenient way that is most often taken to solve such equations like this or the *Wave equation* $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$. Try $$u=f(t)g(\theta)$$therefore $$u_t=u_{\theta\theta}\implies {f'(t)\over f(t)}={g''(\theta)\over g(\theta)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I have no choice to use the convolution...

Comment: In case of FT, does not $u_t$ translate to $j\omega U(\omega)$?